# Amplify and React : Code mismatch and fail enable Software Token MFA

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication, aws-amplify

I have a Cognito user pool that has MFA set to Optional with TOTP only.

I'm trying to set up a page that enables MultiFactorAuthentication for the user for the first time following this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/mfa/q/platform/js#setup-totp).

As my component mounts, I generate a QR code and show it on screen using qrcode.react

```
  useEffect(() => {
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true }).then(user => {
  setUser(user);
  Auth.setupTOTP(user).then(code => {
    const authCode = "otpauth://totp/AWSCognito:" + user.username + "?secret=" + code + "&issuer=ivt";
    setQrCode(authCode);
  });
});
}, []);
```

Then, when the user puts the input, I verify it and call the setPrefferredMFA. Now here, I checked if "input" is correctly passed and no issues there.

```
const setupMFA = input => {
Auth.setupTOTP(user).then(() => {
  Auth.verifyTotpToken(user, input)
    .then(() => {
      Auth.setPreferredMFA(user, "TOTP").then(() => {
        props.setShowModal(false);
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // Token is not verified
    });
});
};
```

I'm still getting **Code mismatch and fail enable Software Token MFA** error and failing to set a MFA to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Auth.verifyTotpToken() is not supposed to be in the .then() block of setupTOTP.

Pfft. Removing the Auth.setupTOTP in the setupMFA function made it work.